# Building a .NET Core console app with ASP.NET Core web server built in?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I see various tutorials online about building a .NET Core console app and building an ASP.NET Core app, but what I don't find is something about building a .NET Core console app that starts with console output but also contains an ASP.NET web app.  In this case I am writing an app that runs as a Windows or a Linux service.  It runs as a daemon.  So I'm now looking to add an ASP.NET Core web interface to output status information.

Is there a recommended way to do this?  I presume I need to create a `WebHostBuilder` and create my new `WebHost` with `.Build()`, but should I create a new project for this and reference it from my console app project?  If so, which SDK should it use for the project?  I can't use `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` because that requires a `Main` method which I obviously don't want to have if this is going to be referenced from an existing app that has its own `Main` method, but if I use `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor`, I seem to get a bunch of dependency version conflicts and errors like:

> Version conflict detected for Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions. Install/reference Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 2.1.1 directly to project MyProject to resolve this issue.

So I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here; what exactly is the best practice for embedding a web app inside a console app in .NET Core?

Comment: The concept you're looking for is "ASP.NET Core Self Host". If you do a web search for that, you should find plenty of useful information.

Comment: @mason Fundamentally though that wants me to keep using the `.Web` SDK which isn't the one I'm using for the console app.  It even causes VS to put a "web app" icon next to the project in the VS solution explorer so it doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but an ASP.NET Core application is already a console application

Comment: Simply reate a web app, it is a console project as long as you run it with kestrell and not iis

Comment: Hosting in Windows service is documented already, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.1 You might post a comment and ask Microsoft to write one for Linux.

Comment: Hi @Jez, have you figured out a solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

You could definitely install the ASP.NET Core packages in your .NET Core project, and build a `WebHost` which will be used as a web server component in your app, as you said yourself. An easy way to do so is by installing the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.App metapackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-2.1), which would include all the package dependencies commonly used for ASP.NET Core apps.

As ASP.NET Core technologies are beyond the scope of my answer, I'll be using brief examples from this point on.

After you have installed the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` metapackage in your project, you can proceed to create a `Startup` class to initialize your server, and develop the app by using ASP.NET Core technologies. A simple `Startup` class to serve as an example:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        /* configure any services you need here */
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        // Output a "hello world" to the user who accesses the server
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello, world!");
        });
    }
}
```

Then you can proceed create a web host with something like that:

```
IWebHost myHost = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();
```

Finally, you must call the `Run()` method in order for your web host to run and start listening for connections:

```
myHost.Run();
```

Run the app and the server will run with some default configs (probably under `http://localhost:5000/` address... server's address/port will be print to your console's output by default). Try accessing the server through your browser and it should print a nice "hello world" message to you.

The `Run()` method is a blocking method. As you already have a console app which you want to "extend" with a web host, you should probably check out the [Start()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhost.start?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IWebHost_Start) method, which fires the web host without blocking your console app, and you can use this in order to still be able to do things, like taking the user's input. There is a small example of doing that in [this doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1#manage-the-host).

Comment: But if you're not using the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK, will the Razor pages get compiled and included in the output properly?

Comment: Use `<FrameworkReference>`